# Transaction underpriced

Tags: remix, erc-20, metamask, contract-deployment

I used the search function, but I didn't find a solution.

We want to create for our new religious NGO a ERC20 token.

I got a sample contract,
a Metamask account,
went to redmix website and connected Metamask.

Copied the adjusted contract (worked)
Set the amoubt of token.
Chosed Inject web3 and didnt nade any changes to gwei/ value.
Clicked deployed
Metamask comes up with the error.

On Metamask is enough ETH to pay the fees.

What do I have to change to make it work please?

Comment: what was the default gwei?

Comment: you are using low gas price

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the error message? That error sometimes appear when there's a pending transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I found the possibility to set the gas price manuel higher. Worked...
But the contract is not able to be vailidated.

I have to do a second contract - and have to pay again.

But one question: how relevant is how I name the file (.sol) itself?

If I say:
AllTogether.sol

Does the name of the coin  of the contract  has to be in exactly the same writing?
Like:
contract AllTogether is ERC20 {
constructor() ERC20("AllTogether", "ATG") {

I am lost...dont want to create - and pay - a not verifiable contract again

Comment: Nop, the name of the .sol file is completely irrelevant. Btw id strongly suggest deploying on testnet while you run your tests to avoid situations like that where you pay fees to deploy something that doesnt work.